# New to scapy. Trying to understand the sr()

Tags: python, scapy

I am new to scapy and I am trying to use the `sr` and `sr1` functions to understand their workings.

I was trying to craft the following packet and I see that it has sent 1 packet but it says that it has received 581 packets. Can someone please help me understand why it's showing so many packets received.

Received 1373 packets, got 0 answers, remaining 1 packets

```
>>> p=sr(IP(dst="192.168.25.1")/TCP(dport=23))
.Begin emission:
.....Finished to send 1 packets.
...............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................^C
Received 581 packets, got 0 answers, remaining 1 packets
>>> p
(<Results: TCP:0 UDP:0 ICMP:0 Other:0>, <Unanswered: TCP:1 UDP:0 ICMP:0 Other:0>)
```

My TCPDump output does not show that it received so many packets.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `sr()` and `sr1()` functions will send a packet and listen on the network for the corresponding answers in the case of `sr()`, `sr1()` will wait for just one answer.

The packets that were received but were not answers are the packets Scapy sniffed while looking for a response to your original packet. I am unsure of how sniffing with `tcpdump` while also using Scapy will affect your results - not sure what process the kernel will pass packets to.

Here is an excellent tutorial on [Sending and Receiving with Scapy](http://thepacketgeek.com/scapy-p-06-sending-and-receiving-with-scapy/) from thePacketGeek.

Also be sure to use the `__doc__` attribute of various Scapy functions in an interpreter to get relevant documentation.

```
>>> print sr1.__doc__
Send packets at layer 3 and return only the first answer
nofilter: put 1 to avoid use of bpf filters
retry:    if positive, how many times to resend unanswered packets
          if negative, how many times to retry when no more packets are answered
timeout:  how much time to wait after the last packet has been sent
verbose:  set verbosity level
multi:    whether to accept multiple answers for the same stimulus
filter:   provide a BPF filter
iface:    listen answers only on the given interface
>>>
```

Comment: FTR: `tcpdump` & scapy & almost any tool (except netfilterqueue-alike) can be run concurrently while all receiving all packets, as they use raw sockets. Also, you should rather use `help(sr1)`